# How to escape square brackets inside square brackets for field name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, escaping

I have some dynamic SQL that generates column names. A quick example might be something like this:

```
SELECT dbo.getSomething(123) [Eggs[scrambled] or Bacon[fried]]
```

The final column name should be this:

> Eggs[scrambled] or Bacon[fried]

If I try to run this it will error on the word OR (even if I replace it with xyz it still errors on that token). The problem is fixed if I take out the inner sets of square brackets. So my conclusion is that you can't nest square brackets unless you somehow escape them.

How do I escape them in this case?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the `quotename` function to see the proper escaping.

```
select quotename('Eggs[scrambled] or Bacon[fried]')
```

Returns

```
[Eggs[scrambled]] or Bacon[fried]]]
```

So all closing square brackets need to be doubled up.

Answer (score 10):

Hang a `]` on the end of inline `[]`

```
   SELECT [Eggs[scrambled]] or Bacon[fried]]] FROM Yummy
```

Comment: @Joe: You should agree that Martin's answer is definitely the best one, as it not only explains the rule but also shows you how to generate the correct name automatically (i.e. without asking on StackOverflow).

Comment: @Andriy His doesn't actually explain the rule (whereas this one does). It just has an example that I have to figure out myself

Comment: @Joe: I thought the last sentence in Martin's answer was a nice explanation. But I won't argue about that, because what seems obvious for someone, can be a bit obscure for someone else. Actually, that's one of the great things about sites like SO: many people can explain the same thing differently, so many other people can pick whatever explanation works best for them.

Answer (score 5):

[SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) is ON by default so no need to escape anything

```
SELECT 1 AS "[Eggs[scrambled] or Bacon[fried]]"
```

Comment: Not quite true that there is no need to escape anything. Quotes will still need escaping!

Comment: Escaping quotes means `SELECT 1 AS "[Eggs""scrambled""or Bacon[fried]]"`?

Answer (score 1):

In an SSIS SQL statement querying an excel sheet you must substitute square brackets for parenthesis to select individual columns.   For example to select "My Column [Great Column]" you would SELECT [My Column (Great Column)] FROM [$A1:AX10000]