# Removing [] around column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, square-bracket

when I was renaming the column in SQL Server, I accidentally inserted the square brackets around the column. The actual statement that I used was:

```
SP_RENAME 'customer.[EMPLOYEENAMES]', '[EMPLOYEENAME]', 'COLUMN'
```

But when I try to retrieve the data it just says and I even tried with out square brackets, it gives the same error

> Invalid column name '[EMPLOYEENAME]'.

How should I remove the square brackets.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `quotename` function, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074826/how-to-escape-square-brackets-inside-square-brackets-for-field-name

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This will restore order in your database:

```
EXEC SP_RENAME 'customer."[EmployeeName]"', 'EmployeeName','COLUMN'
```

You cannot use double brackets because it returns syntax error. Quotes circumvent this limitation.

Answer (score 8):

As you've now got a column with square brackets in the name itself, you can access that column by:

```
SELECT [[EmployeeName]]] 
FROM Customer
```

Yes, all those extra square brackets are a bit unwieldy :)

So, I'd rename your column again to remove the brackets:

```
EXEC SP_RENAME 'customer.[[EmployeeName]]]', 'EmployeeName','COLUMN'
```

So you can then reference "normally":

```
SELECT EmployeeName
FROM Customer
```

Comment: What is the deal-io M$?  Unmatched brackets is valid syntax?  LOL

Answer (score 1):

None of the given alternatives worked for me, so I had to create a new column with the right name, do an update setting newName = [[badName]]], and then drop the wrongly named column.