# Issue with square brackets in alias

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, alias, square-bracket

in my application i generate a query at runtime.

I retrieve a list of fields with values like this ("select fieldvalue as fielddescription"):

```
select
  152 as [weight],
  25 as [length] -- this query text is generated at runtime
```

My problem comes from the field description, that is user defined. In the example above the user named the field "weight" but one option is to name it "weight [kg]" (in the application the user can rename the field as he prefers and it can be that the user chooses square brackets).

In that case my query becomes:

```
select
  152 as [weight [kg]],
  25 as [length]
```

and in this case "[weight [kg]], 25 as [length]" becomes a field alias.
I found a workaround by putting double closure brackets: when i generate they query i replace all "] with "]]", in this case my query becomes:

```
select
  152 as [weight [kg]]], --notice "]]]" = "]]" (substituted) + "]" (closing one)
  25 as [length]
```

and this gives the correct result.

In fact in my implementation i append to select the value and then i add '[' + FIELD_DESCRIPTION + ']' so this is why i have an issue with the square brackets.

If instead of square brackets i used quotes (`select 152 as "weight [kg]"`) i would have a problem with quotes in field description; since i do not want to change the implementation that uses square brackets i do not consider quotes as a solution.

My question is: is it safe to replace "]" with "]]" in my case? Do you see a smarter and safer solution?

Comment: Do you **have** to apply this sort of renaming at the SQL level? Is it not possible to generate a generic result set with just `column0`, `column1`, etc, and then perform the custom naming in the application/report builder/whatever is *consuming* this result set?

Comment: @TT. QUOTENAME would solve the issue in the value part, but in my case the issue is in the alias name, i cannot use QUOTENAME in the alias

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever your approach is a possible way to go, but my implementation is already done and very complex, so i am trying to solve this issue: everything works fine unless a field does not have square brackets in its definition, So to avoid to rewrite all i asked this question.

Comment: somehow the same question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074826/how-to-escape-square-brackets-inside-square-brackets-for-field-name but the accepted answer is not an answer to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials i found out that the solution is ok for my situation.

So I succeded by replacing "]" with "]]" when creating the field alias programmatically, in this way i had no need to change the impelmentation.