# How to escape square brackets inside a SP parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use the stored procedure sp_rename to change column names. However, I get errors when trying to reference the columns because they contain the symbols [ and ]. I can't even to a select:

```
select [Materials].[All] from Temp_Table
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "Materials.All" could not be bound.

"[Materials].[All]" is the name of the column. I've tried it like this:

- select "[Materials].[All]" from Temp_Table
- select [[Materials].[All]] from Temp_Table

Do you see any solutions? Thanks.

EDIT: Ok, some solutions have been presented to make it work in a select statement, but I still get an error when using it in the stored procedure:

```
EXEC sp_rename '[DBName].[Temp_Table].[Materials].[Material Type].[All]]', 'All', 'COLUMN';
```

Error: Syntax error parsing SQL identifier '[KS_Control_Area].[Temp_Table_MaterialType_Mios].[Materials].[Material Type].[All]]'.

Comment: Rename your columns? why would you use `[]` as field names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape square brackets inside square brackets for field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074826/how-to-escape-square-brackets-inside-square-brackets-for-field-name)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it comes like this from the cube. Is from a MDX query...

Comment: @Jonathan yes it could be, however the solutions for that question don't work in the context of the stored procedure sp_rename

Comment: You need to escape only that part of the name that needs escaping, since `sp_rename` accepts multi-part names, and when using a four-part name you must include the schema. So `EXEC sp_rename '[DBName].[dbo].[Temp_Table]."[Materials].[All]"', ...` (or just `[Temp_Table]."[Materials].[All]"`, leaving out DB and schema).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote you column's name correctly. So, for a column named `silly[column]name` you would use `[silly[column]]name]`. Note that the `[` inside the name doesn't need be escaped, however the `]` does (to `]]`).

Comment: I tried it but I still get the syntax error. This still threw an error: EXEC sp_rename '[DBName].[Temp_Table].[[Materials]].[Material Type]].[All]]]', 'All', 'COLUMN';

Comment: That looks like you have too many object parts. the correct syntax would be: `USE DBName; EXEC sp_rename 'Temp_Table.[[Materials]].[All]]]', 'All', 'COLUMN';`. Based on the fact that your column is called `[Materials].[All]` (as per your question posted)

Comment: sorry for making it confusing. Your solution worked. I also found out that you can do a SELECT QUOTENAME('silly[column]name') to get the right syntax. Thanks!