# SQL Server : batch with specific characters of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, batch-file

I wrote a batch script with SQL statements in order to export data to a `.csv` file:

```
sqlcmd -S DBServer -U User -P Password -d DBName -s"," 
       -Q "SET NOCOUNT on;SELECT <=0.1%, (0.1%,0.5%] FROM t" -o D:\output.csv ;
```

But the specific characters in column name `<=0.1%`、`(0.1%,0.5%]` make the batch file is not working.

What should be the correct approach for this select statement?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess you need to escape the less-than sign like `^<` and the percent signs by `%%`…

Comment: SELECT <=0.1%, (0.1%,0.5%] FROM t. Does this query run successfully?. It looks incorrect

Comment: @aschipfl thank you. I tried and now `select <=0.1%` works but `select (0.1%,0.5%]` still can not work. Is there any solution?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Yes. The statement of `SELECT "<=0.1%", "(0.1%,0.5%]" FROM t` works in SQL. But can not work in batch.

Comment: Case if  those are weird name of columns `SELECT [<=0.1%], [(0.1%,0.5%]]] FROM t`

Comment: @Serg It finally works with `SELECT [<=0.1%%], [(0.1%%,0.5%%]]] FROM t` Thank you. There is still a question. `[(0.1%%,0.5%%]]]` would  be divided into two columns in csv file because of `,` What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps export from a view that aliases these column names to names that don't need delimiting.

Comment: As your `-Q` argument string is already enclosed within double-quotes normal poison characters should already be protected. The only issue therefore is that a batch file has an added problem as `%` characters are special. You should only need to double those percent characters to escape them, nothing else should need touching. `sqlcmd -S DBServer -U User -P Password -d DBName -s"," -Q "SET NOCOUNT on;SELECT <=0.1%%, (0.1%%,0.5%%] FROM t" -o D:\output.csv ;`

Comment: @varen, as Stu suggested use an alias `SELECT [<=0.1%%], [(0.1%%,0.5%%]]] [(0.1%%_0.5%%]]]  FROM t`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape square brackets inside square brackets for field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074826/how-to-escape-square-brackets-inside-square-brackets-for-field-name)